# WPF DateTimePicker Control for .Net 3.5

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-3.5, wpf-controls, datetimepicker

Im developing an application in Vb.Net 3.5 under WPF.I need to implement the date picker in it.How can i get that control in WPF.How can i implement in XAML. It says that DatetimePicker and Calendar are not supported.

I tried installing - Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF nugget but again it can't because it is not supported. Does anyone know what to do.
And apperantly we can't add any nugget package to the program. Thank you!

Comment: Why net 3.5? That's long obsolete.

Comment: There is no `DateTimePicker` control in WPF. There is a `DatePicker` control.

Comment: *"apperantly we can't add any nugget package to the program"*. That's not the case. Most likely you just did something wrong, like trying to install a package that doesn't support that version. I just looked at the latest version of that NuGet package and it specifically states that it requires .NET Framework 4.x. The same goes for version 16, which is the oldest.

Comment: Win xp is compatible with .net4. Win xp is way beyond it's sell by date and out of support. Why would you possibly decide net3.5 is a good idea? If you went with .net 4 you could use the xceed toolkit